# Transpose table with categorical data in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table in Excel:

```
category label value
A        green 2
A        red   1
A        blue  4
B        green 0
B        red   3
B        blue  2
```

How it can be transposed as follows through VBA macro?

```
category green red blue
A        2     1   4
B        0     3   2
```

Comment: Using a pivot table is the simplest for the example you give.  But, in your comment to @MichałTurczyn, you indicate this example is not representative of your data. If you don't provide representative data, and desired output from that data, you may not receive a solution that is suitable for your real data.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to use pivot table:

1. Select whole table
2. Go into Insert tab and click "Pivot Table"
3. Then you need to drag and drop appropriate columns into correct fields, i.e. `label` to columns, `category` to rows and `value` to values.

Something like this (I named `category` column as `cat`):

[image]

[Pivot tables in excel](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

Comment: The reason for asking it via VBA, I have some other code where this one is supposed to be a part of. I could not find a way to get it with Pivot Table. 
And also your table is summing "value", while the request is to return actual values from original table.

Comment: @anarz It's summing them, but also outputs correct values as desired.

Comment: True that. But it will not work when values are string. (I have some strings too)

Comment: @anarz If you don't provide data and desired output representative of your **real** data, you may not receive an applicable solution.